# Passing multiple parameters to function using onclick

Tags: javascript

I am making a todo app. When I click the edit button i want to send the items id and title to the editItem function. I am having trouble with figuring out how to pass to parameters using template strings. It works fine when I just send item.id but when I add the second parameter (item.title) I get an error

```
<button onclick='data.editItem(${item.id}, ${item.title})'class="editItem">Edit</button>
```

full code

```
const data = new State()

data.mockData.map(item => {
    let markup =` <li  id="${item.id}"className={item.done ? 'done': 'hidden'}> ${item.title}
<button onclick='data.deleteItem(${item.id})'class="deleteItem" >Delete</button>
<button onclick='data.editItem(${item.id}${item.title})'class="editItem">Edit</button>
<button class="completeItem">Complete</button>
</li>
`
document.querySelector('ul').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup)
```

})

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: There are many ways to learn something. One way is trying to create it by yourself, but that often fails. And this is your case, because you ended up here. The other way is studying someone else's work who knows better. At this point maybe you'd like to check out http://todomvc.com/

Comment: There are a couple of problems here that will prevent this from working as you would expect. 1) you need to use backticks rather then single quotes; 2) you need to encapsulate the attribute with double quotes. 3) this won't work though because `item` is undefined here.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a slightly different approach than yours, but would something like this work for you?

```
<li id="item1">
Item1 Title
  <button id="button1" onclick="handleClick(this.id)" class="editItem">
      Edit
  </button>
</li>

<script>
    function editItem(id, title) {
        console.log(id, title)
    }

    function handleClick(id) {
         let clickedButton = document.getElementById(id);
       let item1 = clickedButton.parentNode;
       editItem(item1.id, item1.firstChild.textContent);
    }

</script>
```

*Note: I've edited the code above to further address questioner's need.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try use with quotes:

```
<button onclick='data.editItem(${item.id}, "${item.title}")'class="editItem">Edit</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

I think it should be;
`<button onclick="editItem(item.id, item.title)" />`

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.